# How to debounce mui Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to debounce `onInputChange` function

```
export interface AutocompleteProps<V extends FieldValues> {
  onInputChange: UseAutocompleteProps<UserOrEmail, true, false, false>['onInputChange'];
}
export default function MyAutocomplete<V extends FieldValues>({
  onInputChange
}: AutocompleteProps<V>) {

  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <Autocomplete<UserOrEmail, true, false, false>

          onInputChange={onInputChange} //here

        />
      )}
    />
  );
```

I have done it like this(used debounce outside and passing it like a prop) and it works

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
const searchDelayed = useCallback(
    debounce((newValue: string) => setSearch(newValue), 100),
    []
  );
      //Passing the prop like this
        /*
           onInputChange={(_, newValue) => {
                        searchDelayed(newValue);
                      }}
        */
```

I want to debounce in `MyAutocomplete` but I can not call `onInputChange` in `debounce` function. If I do not call it then I get an error, and it does not work

```
const searchsDelayed = useCallback( //does not work
     debounce(() => onInputChange, 100),
    [onInputChange]
  );
```

Any ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 5):

There is an inbuilt MUI debounce utility to use. You can import it like this

`import { debounce } from '@mui/material/utils'`

And you can find official MUI implement example over here [MUI Autocomplete with debounce](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#search-as-you-type)

Answer (score 4):

[Answer reviewed to avoid confusion.]

The main issue is here:

```js
debounce(() => onInputChange, 100);
```

you are debouncing a function that returns `onInputChange`, it doesn't invoke it, and it would be needed to be called twice.
To fix this, just pass `onInputChange` directly:

```js
debounce(onInputChange, 100);
```

---

Anyway, you are trying to use `useCallback` but you probably would be fine without any optimization anyway, so you could use

```js
const searchDelayed = debounce(onInputChange, 100);
```

But if you actually need the optimization, in this case you should use `useMemo` since you need the result of the debounce invocation:

```js
const searchDelayed = useMemo(
    () => debounce(onInputChange, 100),
    [onInputChange]
);
```

Comment: I tried to use it like this but `onInputChange ` is not invoked at all

Comment: I might have missed something then, I'll review it

Comment: No need, this question is bad, and I probably do not need it

Comment: I reviewed the answer anyway, I made a change and added some notes. I tested it on StackBlitz so it's working